# find if string starts with sub string using std::equal

Tags: c++, string, c++11

May you please point me to what is the wrong thing I am doing here?

```
auto is_start_with = [](std::string const& whole_string, std::string const& starting_substring)->bool{
        if (starting_substring.size() > whole_string.size()) return false;
        return std::equal(begin(starting_substring), end(starting_substring), begin(whole_string));
    };
```

It is always return true.

I know there is many many other solutions but I want to know what is the error here.

**EDIT :**

Debuging!
[image]

P.S. I tried it in other main file with directly entering the strings and it worked!!

**Edit 2:**

I deleted two to lower transforms before the comparison and it worked!

```
std::transform(std::begin(fd_name), std::end(fd_name), std::begin(fd_name), ::tolower);
std::transform(std::begin(type_id), std::end(type_id), std::begin(type_id_lower), ::tolower);
```

Comment: Show us some test cases, at first glance it seems that it's OK.

Comment: Looks [fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60aa2f0fc14400ad) to me.

Comment: a screenshot from the debugging process was added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use such long identifiers like `whole_string` or `starting_substring`. It is clear enough from the parameter declaration that the lambda deals with strings. Too long names make the code less readable.
And there is no sense to use general functions `std::begin` and `std::end`. The lambda is written specially for strings.

Also you could use only one return statement.`For example

```
auto is_start_with = []( std::string const &source, std::string const &target )
{
    return !( source.size() < target.size() ) &&
           std::equal( target.begin(), target.end(), source.begin() );
}
```

Or even like

```
auto is_start_with = []( std::string const &source, std::string const &target )
{
    return ( not ( source.size() < target.size() ) ) &&
           std::equal( target.begin(), target.end(), source.begin() );
}
```